# grid-time visualization of scheduled processes

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, visualization

The data ETL software environment we use at work runs some 20 scheduled processes. I would like to be able to visualize a time-based grid with these processes to quickly check what is running now() and what is scheduled later in the day, week, etc..

I am looking for some open source component to display this in a web page in some simple grid timeline fashion. I would also like to express dependencies and constraints between scheduled (like for instance https://bryntum.com/examples/scheduler-pro/dependencies/) These schedules are configured in some json-like files which I could easily convert to true json, yaml or anything else that could be fed to this visualization component. I have taken a look in github.com but did not find something that fits my needs. Can anyone provide me with some hints or pointers to something existing?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of simple scheduler and timeline widgets are available for free or open-source.

- https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline
- https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline
- https://fullcalendar.io/

As far as I know, there is no OS scheduler with constraints and dependencies capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your hints @Mats, very useful! And congratulations on your products, they look great ;-)